# Example of a function on $[0,2]$ with no maximum of minimum

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

Can anybody help me by providing an example of a function (or the graph of such a function) defined on $[0, 2]$ but with no maximum and no minimum? An explanation is also appreciated.

#### Context

Such a function will have to be discontinuous, because we have a theorem that says a continuous function on a closed interval must attain its maximum and minimum.

Also, it cannot be monotone, because monotone functions attain max/min values at the endpoints.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x$ if $0\lt x\lt 2$, and $f(0)=f(2)=1$.

This function is not continuous on $]0,2]$. That is unavoidable, since a function continuous on a closed interval $[a,b]$ attains a maximum and a minimum on that interval.

Answer (score 1):

You want a function without any max/min on [0,2]

How about $f(x) = 0$

Comment: No *isolated* extrema here, but otherwise there is both a minimum and a maximum in every element in $[0,2]$...

Comment: Didn't think that the Sohel was asking a question with that much detail, but just a basic high school algebra class.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
   \dfrac{1}{x-1} & \text{If $x \ne 1.$} \\
   \phantom{mi}0  & \text{If $x = 1.$} \\
\end{cases} $